How to declare types of ref variables in typescript with vuejs composition api?
I'm new to both TypeScript and Vuejs and am facing some TypeScript warnings. Here is the snippet of the entire code:
const logJson = ref([])
const logs = ref()

logs.value = logJson.value.filter((Log) => 
  Log.timestamp
  .toLowerCase()
  .includes(searchText.value.toLowerCase()) || 
  Log.logType
  .toLowerCase()
  .includes(searchText.value.toLowerCase()) || 
  Log.logMessage
  .toLowerCase()
  .includes(searchText.value.toLowerCase()))

let timestamp: string,
  logType: string,
  logMessage: string

logJson.value.push({timestamp: timestamp, logType: logType, logMessage: logMessage})

Here timestamp, logType and logMessage (values of the object) are variables with type string.
E.g. entry of logJson:
{
  timestamp: "2024-05-07 08:51:06",
  logType: "INFO",
  logMessage: "mailbox allocated for rsvp"
}

I'm getting the following errors:
Argument of type { timestamp: string; logType: string; logMessage: string; } is not assignable to parameter of type never.
Property timestamp does not exist on type never.
Property logType does not exist on type never.
Property logMessage does not exist on type never.
How should the type of logJson, logs, Log, timestamp, logType, logMessage (keys of the object) be written?

To resolve the TypeScript errors, you need to define proper types for logJson and logs refs like this:
type LogEntry = {
  timestamp: string;
  logType: string;
  logMessage: string;
};

const logJson = ref<LogEntry[]>([]);
const logs = ref<LogEntry[]>([]);

